# Retrieving a substring from a string whose size changes

Tags: java, string

I have a String `"1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.0.0 = 47"`. How can I retrieve the RHS part of the equations, which is `"47"`? I cannot use the `substr(StartIndex, EndIndex)`, because the size of my LHS will change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [String JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) have the answer

Comment: Hi, isn't this a XY problem? (http://xyproblem.info/) - it looks like you are doing something with SNMP and in that case, there may be more suitable ways to solve your problem...

Comment: I think @Mike is right - looks very SNMP-like to me. If this is so, perhaps check out an SNMP library like: [link](https://jsevy.com/snmp/snmp_package_introduction.html)

Comment: Just for the record: you haven't accepted any of the answers yet. Please consider doing that at some point.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) to first fetch the position of that "=" within your string.

In other words: most of the time, strings do not have a **fixed** (column based) layout; in that sense: checking your string for its *actual* content is the most natural thing in the world. You can use those low-level methods like indexOf(), lastIndexOf(), ... or you go one step further and use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to get more complicated jobs done.

Alternatively, you can also use methods like String.split() in order to turn your input string into an array of substrings; based on the given "split" pattern.

Comment: Up-voted for pointing out that regular expressions are not needed for this simple case.

Comment: @VGR Thanks. I will remember to do that more often then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

No need to use substring
RHS will also be after "=" so you can split your string from "="

```
String string = "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.0.0 = 47";
String[] parts = string.split("=");
String LHS= parts[0]; // 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.0.0
String RHS= parts[1]; // 47
```

this way you can get LHS and RHS both

better to check for the original string is not null otherwise it will give nullPointerException

Comment: Might be useful to use `split("\\s*=\\s*")` to trim out any whitespace either side of the equals sign, too.  And don't forget to test the `length()` of the returned array, just in case the input string was in an invalid format (i.e., had 0 or more than one = in it).

Comment: even easier `String RHS= parts[1].trim();` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the string only contains a single equals, you could split it into an array of two strings, then get the second one:

```
String s = "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.0.0 = 47";
String rhs = s.split("= ")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string base on "="

```
str.split("=")[1].trim() will return your RHS part.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` your String taking `=` as separator. And you will have your LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one "=" in the string, you could do something like this:

```
int start = searchString.indexOf("=") + 1;
String lhs = searchString.substring(start).trim();
```

Plus some error handling...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regex :

```
final String test = "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.0.0 = 47";
final String regex = ".*= (.*)";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result :

```
47
```